# How to write this objective c syntax in to swift 2.0 syntax?

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

```
NSArray *arrayTemp = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"asd", @"szdfasd", @"dsfgfdf", nil];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:arrayTemp, @"temp_array", nil];

NSString result =  [((NSArray ) [dict objectForKey:@"temp_array"]) objectAtIndex:(arrayTemp.count -1)];
```

Comment: should we also copy the syntax errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let arrayTemp = ["asd", "szdfasd", "dsfgfdf"]
let dict = ["temp_array" : arrayTemp]
let result = dict["temp_array"]!.last!
```

Comment: you forgot to copy 7 errors

Comment: I didn't know how to translate them ;-)